# Have three points for two different arcs, which arc is longest?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Arc 1:

- Center: $(-0.00,   2.19)$
- End point of the arc: $(0, 7.43)$
- Beginning point of the arc: $(-5.19,  2.9)$

Arc 2:

- Center: $(-0.725, 0.931223)$
- End point of the arc: $(-0.012508,  6.053215)$
- Beginning point of the arc: $(-5.19, 2.9)$

I cannot figure out which one of these have the longest arc segment, I dont need to know the exacts length but approximately which one is the longest. I get that arc 1 is longest after doing some sketches, and was wondering if anyone could help me double check.

The three points are not meant to perfectly align, these are just approximations.

Comment: Draw the figure that you think represents the data. Are you able to calculate the radius? Label the knowns. What can you figure from there?

Comment: . You have $-0.00,2,19$, so it this a three dimensional point and why not $-0.00=0$?

Comment: 1) the begin/end point of 2nd arc doesn't lie on a circle centered at given center. 2) the radius in 1st arc > the two "distances to center" in 2nd arc. 3) the angle subtended by 1st arc at center > the angle for 2nd arc. So first arc is definitely longer.

Comment: Something seems wrong with the first arc points!

Comment: The first point was wrong, it was supposed to be 2.19, not 2,19

Comment: By center, do you mean "center of the circle the arc belongs to" (the arc passes through begin/end, not center - this is my interpretation) or "a point  on the arc between begin/end" (i.e. the arc passes through begin/center/end in that order - interpretation in Ivan's answer)?

Answer (score 1):

Case 1: $B_1=(0,7.43)$, $C_1=(-0,2.19)$, $E_1=(-5.19,2.19)$

$D_1=$ middle of $B_1C_1=(0,4.81)$, $n_1=$ normal to $B_1C_1=(1,0)$.

$F_1=$ middle of $C_1E_1=(-2.595,2.19)$, $m_1=$ normal to $C_1E_1=(0,1)$.

$O_1=$ center of arc $=D_1+u_1n_1=F_1+v_1m_1$

$O_1=(0+u_1,4.81)=(-2.595,2.19+v_1)\Rightarrow u_1=-2.595 \Rightarrow O_1=(-2.595,4.81)$

$O_1B_1=(2.595,2.62)$, radius is $\sqrt{2.595^2+2.62^2}=3.69$.

$O_1E_1=(-2.595,-2.62)=-O_1B_1$, therefore arc is exactly one half of circle. Length of arc is $3.69\pi<11.6$

Case 2: $B_2=(-5.19,2.9)$, $C_2=(-0.725,0.931223)$, $E_2=(-0.012508,6.053125)$

$D_2=(-2.9575,1.9156115)$, $n_2=(1.968777,4.465)$.

$F_2=(-0.368754,3.492174)$, $m_2=(-5.121902,0.712492)$.

$O_2=D_2+u_2n_2=F_2+v_2m_2$

$u_2=0.4086876, v_2=0.3483372, O_2=(-2.152903,3.740361)$

$O_2B_2=(-3.037097,-0.84036146)$, radius is $3.1512$, slope is $-\pi+\arctan(0.84036146/3.037097)=-2.872$ radians.

$O_2C_2=(1.428,-2.809)$, slope is $\arctan(-2.809/1.428)=-1.1005$ radians.

$O_2E_2=(2.140,2.313)$, slope is $\arctan(2.313/2.140)=0.824$ radians. Length of arc is $3.1512\cdot(0.824+2.872)>11.6$. The second arc is slightly longer than first. The difference is about 0.4 %, so you need to give your coordinates with at least such precision.